# Javascript logging to file on local computer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, logging, angularjs-log

I need to create log from web application in Chrome(angularjs/javascript) on client/local machine. Any idea how to do that?

I couldn't use activeX object in Chrome.

Comment: What's the purpose of the log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly do this. You could use [StackTrace.js](https://www.stacktracejs.com/) to push the stacktrace to the server and then read it back in your web application or make it available as a download.

Comment: That's what I thought, I will have to use stacktrace or log4js.

Answer (score 1):

You can't log to local machine, some suggestions

- Window.localStorage - the amount of data you can log is very small, most browsers support this but size limits vary.
- Chrome also supports WebSQL (I don't know if it will drop this in the future) space is limited to 5MB, other browser support is different.
- Install other software to do the logging. (Using any for of ajax request to talk to a server listening on http(s)://localhost:port. e.g. You could use [socket.io](http://socket.io/) to make a logger in node.js)
- Log to the server. (Using any for of ajax request.)